# Instagram Graph API - Insights

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

Does anyone here have access to the Graph API? I have a general question. I see a service/tool who has the insight data of +100M Instagram Users. I see the Graph API offers Insights - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/insights/

My question is, with the Graph API, can you access any accounts followers Insight data? Or does the user in question require approval before their data could be accessed through the Graph API? Are there any methods to access an accounts followers insight data?

This is the only way I can think of on how this tool is accessing everyone's data without permissions.

Thanks

Comment: "This is the only way I can think of on how this tool is accessing everyone's data without permissions." That's very likely. They're probably scraping. Hard to say for certain without the actual tool in question, and access to its code, but Facebook has locked down this sort of data everywhere else in the API already.

Comment: I thought of that, but can you image scraping the insight data of every single Instagram user on the platform? Over 100M users and keeping that data up to date? I can't see that....  I can't image that being possible without the use of an API. I thought they may have used Graph API.

Comment: It's entirely possible. Google scrapes somewhere in the hundreds of trillions of pages. 100M is peanuts if they've got a good revenue stream.

Comment: I think it's a little unfair to compare Google to some little guy living in his apartment apparently scraping 1B Instagram accounts and updating the data daily.  He not only has the 100M users in the db, he has the data on all of their followers as well.  So he's not using the Graph API for this?

Comment: We cannot tell you for certain what "he" is doing, especially without details on who "he" is. We can make educated guesses; mine is still that he's scraping. https://s3.amazonaws.com/lambda-tools/pricing-calculator.html indicates Lambda can do 100M requests at an average execution time of 500ms for $100/month or so. The Graph API does not give you insights on your followers (beyond their interactions with you directly), and it doesn't permit you to look up others' insights, just your own.

Comment: Also, if he is scraping, how does he get insights like audience gender etc? That's not in the html.

Answer (score 2):

Typically graph won't allow you to access anyone who isn't a user, or follower of your software.  Therefore I would assume not, they dont even give you the user_id until the user explicitly uses your software.

Comment: I heard this also, I was getting mixed results.  Some have mentioned to me that you require the users token and permissions in order to access their data.  Some have mentioned that with the Graph API, we can access anyones data, which also wold make sense with how this one tool I know has not only 100M accounts in their database, they also have their followers insight data as well.  I just can't see this being possible with a scraping tool, especially to keep the data updated and refreshed on a go forward basis.

Comment: Yes, it seems to me you just get the information surrounding the webhook and the interaction with your material.

Comment: I see, so he's not using the Graph API then for this?

Comment: I cannot say, if he had a lot of traffic I imagine he would gain access to a large amount of data

Comment: @JohnKramer did you ever find an answer to this?